# Twitter streaming in R, "Error in vector("list", ntimes) : invalid 'length' argument"?

Tags: r, twitter, error-handling, purrr, rtweet

I am trying to steam some tweets.

The code is as follows;

```
Supplier_List <- data.frame(companies = c("company1","company2","company3"))

Streamed_Tweets <- purrr::map_df(Supplier_List$companies, ~{
  search_tweets2(.x, retryonratelimit = TRUE,include_rts=FALSE,lang="en")
  #Sys.sleep(5)
}, .id = 'id')
```

The error that comes up is

**Error in vector("list", ntimes) : invalid 'length' argument**

Could anyone please help me?